# Bottom panel missing on CentOS on full screen VirtualBox

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, centos

I am running CentOS as guest on VirtualBox from Windows 7 host.

When I switch my resolution to a lower one, the bottom panel looks fine:

[image]

But when I use the max resolution of my monitor (1600x900), the bottom panel is gone. When I try to take a screenshot, it appears on print screen image but in reality it's not there.

Anyone knows how to fix it?

EDIT: I realize the resolution I selected was 1600x1200. That make sense. But now my problem is there is no 1600x900 option.

Comment: If you move your mouse to the bottom of the screen, where the panel should be, and then you take a screenshot, is the cursor over the panel?  In other words, is the panel missing, or is it being cut off by the monitor?

Comment: @Nick2253 When using "print screen" I can see the bottom panel in the image produced by the print screen command although it's not there while I'm doing the print screen. So I guess it's both missing and it's being cut off?

Comment: I understand your problem.  My diagnostic step is to try and figure out why it's missing, be it cut off or just absence.  Physically move the cursor to the bottom edge of your screen (don't just slam the cursor down all the way, bring it up so you can just see the tip of it), and take another print screen.  If the tip of the cursor is over the panel, we know that it's missing.  However, if the tip of the cursor is above the panel, we know it's being cut off.

Comment: @Nick2253 Ok I realize the resolution I selected was 1600x1200. That make sense. But now my problem is there is no 1600x900 option.

Comment: Have you installed the VirtualBox Guest Additions?

Comment: @Nick2253 I did but it looks like it didn't went well. I get the message `Building the main Guest Additions module [FAILED]` And this was in the logs: `/tmp/vbox.0/Makefile.include.header:97: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
Creating user for the Guest Additions.
Creating udev rule for the Guest Additions kernel module.`

Comment: This should help you install the guest additions correctly: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Virtualization/VirtualBox/CentOSguest

Comment: @Nick2253 It works now thanks. If you want to add an "official" answer I will accept it :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing the CentOS guest additions:

http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Virtualization/VirtualBox/CentOSguest